# Need help with Swift mailer with Kohana wrapper

Tags: php, email, kohana, kohana-3, swiftmailer

My current code is this

```
$swift = email::connect();


        $swift->setSubject('hello')
              ->setFrom(array('alex@example.com.au' => 'Alex'))
              ->setTo(array('alex@example.com.au' => 'Alex'))
              ->setBody('hello')  
              ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath(DOCROOT . 'assets/attachments/instructions.pdf'));

        $swift->send();
```

The `email::connect()` [returns an instance of SwiftMailer](http://github.com/banks/kohana-email/blob/master/classes/email.php#L70).

As per [these docs](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-quickref), it would seem that it should work.

However, I get an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Swift_Mailer::setSubject() in /home/user/public_html/application/classes/controller/properties.php  on line 45
```

I've seen that `email::connect()` does exactly what the example code in the docs does. That is

- include the correct file
- return an instance of the library

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `Swift_Mailer` instance, not a `Swift_Message` like in the example you linked to.

I think you want something like this:

```
$swift = email::connect();
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

        $message->setSubject('hello')
              ->setFrom(array('alex@example.com.au' => 'Alex'))
              ->setTo(array('alex@example.com.au' => 'Alex'))
              ->setBody('hello')  
              ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath(DOCROOT . 'assets/attachments/instructions.pdf'));

        $swift->send($message);
```

Comment: Cursed by late Friday afternoon. Thanks mate and have a good weekend! BTW, I've seen you're from Brisbane, I'd buy you a beer if you lived 100km north :P

Comment: @alex: Thanks, I don't actually drink (the hardest I drink would probably be a *ginger* beer). Have a good weekend too!